# Работа script по тригуру на onFormSubmit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Что изменить в коде чтобы при проверке ответов сообщение в телеграм не отправлялось, а отправлялось только когда ответ поступает при заполнении формы. Коротка о работе: При заполнении формы ответ падает на лист Таблицы последней строкой и отправляеться информация в телеграм с данными этой строки. Форма настроена в виде теста и уже при проверке ответа с формы оценка за тест падает в Таблицу и так как форма настроена по тригуру на отправку, то очередной раз приходит информация с данными последней строки.  Спасибо.

````
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const token = '';

const getSheetById = (id) => ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getSheetId() === id)[0];

const swOrder = getSheetById(1548815933);
const swWorkers = getSheetById(997577871);

function sendTelegram() {
  let lastRow = swOrder.getLastRow();
  let workers = swWorkers.getRange(2, 1, swWorkers.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  let nameManager = swOrder.getRange(lastRow, 5).getValue();
  let flatManagers = workers.flat();
  let rowManager = flatManagers.indexOf(nameManager) + 2;
  let chatId = swWorkers.getRange(rowManager, 2).getValue();
  let data = swOrder.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, 5).getDisplayValues()[0];
  let name = ss.getName();
  let url = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl();
  let text = `
  ${name}
 ${data[3]}
 ${url} `
  sendText(chatId, text)
}

function sendText(chatId, text) {
  let data = {
    method: 'sendMessage',
    chat_id: String(chatId),
    text: text,
    parse_mode: 'HTML'
  };
  let options = {
    method: 'post',
    payload: data
  
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', options)
}```
````

Comment: Что значит " при проверке ответов"? Такого события нет.

Comment: при проверке ответа значит при оценке ответа учителем так как учитель с формы проставляет бал учекнику